# Remote Filtering on Grid in extjs 5

Tags: extjs5

Below is my Store. I'm using "remoteFilter:true" on store and when I'm search data in extjs grid column then that data doesn't set on that field for search remote.

```
Ext.define('ProjMgmtApp.store.Risk', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
  model: 'ProjMgmtApp.model.Risk',
  autoLoad: true,
  pageSize: utilsObj.scrollValue,
  remoteFilter:true,
  remoteSort:true,
  proxy: {
      type: 'ajax',
      url: utilsObj.wrapPKID('RiskList'),
      reader: {
        type: 'json',
        rootProperty: 'results',
        totalProperty: 'totalCount',
        successProperty: 'success'
      }
  }
});
```

My grid column which I want to filter, and it's only work on local filter not remote filter but I want remote filter, please advice me,thanks all of you.

```
{
  header: "Description",
  dataIndex: 'riskDescription',
  width: 50,
  sortable: true,
  filter:{
    type: 'string'
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you implemented filtering on server side? Have you checked in browser developer tools that filter has or hasn't been submited?

Comment: Yes i have implemented filtering on server side,it also works on extjs 4, but not work in extjs 5.

Comment: I don't see any problem with your code, it should work. I made demo few days ago: http://jsfiddle.net/seur2aLx/11/ to another question, paging is working there, try this, maybe you'll find something helpful there.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Facing the same...